# Declaring character encodings in HTML

Tags: html, character-encoding, meta, http-equiv

Should I declare charset like this:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html" charset="utf-8" />
```

or like this:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
```

Or are both valid?

Comment: It doesn't make a difference, but if you see most web pages use just charset="utf-8"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated in light of @Alohci's comment.

See [W3C's documentation on `<meta http-equiv="...">`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/meta):

> #### encoding declaration state (`http-equiv="content-type"`)
>
> The encoding declaration state is ***just an alternative form of setting the `charset` attribute***: it is a character encoding declaration. This state's user agent requirements are all handled by the parsing section of the specification.
>
> For meta elements with an `http-equiv` attribute in the Encoding declaration state, the content attribute ***must*** have a value that is an ASCII case-insensitive match for a string that consists of: the literal string `"text/html;"`, ***optionally followed by any number of space characters, followed by the literal string `"charset="`, followed by one of the labels of the character encoding of the character encoding declaration.***
>
> ***A document must not contain both a meta element with an `http-equiv` attribute in the encoding declaration state and a meta element with the `charset` attribute present.*** (*emphasis mine*)

Therefore, if you are going to use `http-equiv`, it must be used as `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">`. But, that's just another way of saying `<meta charset="utf-8">`, so use the abbreviated form.

Comment: MDN is wrong. `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">` is not invalid or obsolete in HTML5. See http://w3c.github.io/html/document-metadata.html#statedef-http-equiv-content-type or try it in a validator.

Comment: @Alohci Thank you for pointing that out. I corrected my answer.

Answer (score 4):

The both declarations are valid, you could always use the short equivalent version :

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

Because you start a document with

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

I doubt that it's necessary to specify the content type. Instead just specify the encoding/charset:

```
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
```